# Spark task fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, spring-data-cassandra

Am trying to create a spring boot (2.7.5) project that write to Cassandra (using spring data cassandra) and read from Cassandra with spark. It works fine when I provide spark master as local[*] it works fine but when I try to connect to spark cluster master URL am getting as error as below.

Cassandra version - 4.0.1

Spark version - 3.1.3

```
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Code generated in 2093.165617 ms
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Starting job: show at HomeController.java:26
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Got job 0 (show at HomeController.java:26) with 1 output partitions
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Final stage: ResultStage 0 (show at HomeController.java:26)
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Parents of final stage: List()
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Missing parents: List()
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at show at HomeController.java:26), which has no missing parents
2022-11-17 11:45:03 - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 16.9 KiB, free 2.2 GiB)
2022-11-17 11:45:04 - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 7.8 KiB, free 2.2 GiB)
2022-11-17 11:45:04 - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.10.16.83:33309 (size: 7.8 KiB, free: 2.2 GiB)
2022-11-17 11:45:04 - Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1433
2022-11-17 11:45:04 - Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at show at HomeController.java:26) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
2022-11-17 11:45:04 - Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
2022-11-17 11:45:04 - Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (10.10.16.83, executor 0, partition 0, ANY, 6302 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
2022-11-17 11:45:04 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (10.10.16.83 executor 0): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
```

Dependency list

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me to fix dependencies if there is any conflict and let me know that how to run my spring boot project to connect to spark cluster. currently an running project using java -- jar command

Comment: It depends on how have you built your application - have you made an uberjar from it?